# Using fontcolor() in Google Sheets Returns HTML in Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my sheet, I want to automatically take negative numbers, change the color to red, and remove the '-' character. The number in a cell can fluctuate between positive and negative, based on data in other cells eg...

```
A1 = "some number"
A2 = "some number"
A3 = A1 + A2 (number should be red if value is a negative, and '-' 
     should be stripped off. Otherwise number should be black.
```

I've written an apps script that should do this

```
function negativesToRed(num) {
      if (num < 0) {
        var newNum = (num * -1).toString();
        var redNum = newNum.fontcolor("red");
      }
      return redNum;
    }
```

but when I use it, it returns...

`<font color="red">605</font>`

...in the cell.

NOTE: A3 needs to turn red when data inputted in A1 or A2 changes it to a negative. onEdit() will only work if user manually changes A3 to a negative number. AND if the value in A3 is used elsewhere, it needs to be treated as a negative number (removing '-' is just for display).

Is there anyway to get this to work?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you only manipulate the value of the cell. Read the answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195002/how-to-change-format-of-cell-that-runs-function-google-sheets-script-editor) . As far as I understand, you get the value of the cell to the function, and it only returns a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this in AppsScript for display purposes.  Instead of changing the value of the cell, you can just change the way the number format is displayed.  Set positive numbers to display as black, and negative numbers to display as red without the negative (-) sign showing.  For example, to change the display of just column 10:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetIDhere').getSheetByName('sheetNameHere');
ss.getRange(2, 10,ss.getLastRow()-1, 1).setNumberFormat('[Black]#,##0;[Red]#,##0;');
```

You can also update the number format of the cell/column/sheet by selecting the columns you want to change the view on in the Sheet itself, click on Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom Format -> and entering [Black]#,##0;[Red]#,##0; into the custom area.

Comment: Using - Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom Format -> and entering [Black]#,##0;[Red]#,##0 - Turned out to be the easiest and most effective solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can only return value from the custom script function. In order to change the cell color, you can try adding a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), such as `onEdit`, and then apply `setFontColor` to a cell.

Comment: I tried `onEdit()`. It works when I manually change a value, but won't work on a value when it is indirectly changed by other values. Updated question explanation to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

By using `onEdit` you can manipulate the cell, and not only the value.

Something like this, unless you want to restrict it more.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (e.value < 0) {
        range.setValue(e.value * -1);
        range.setFontColor('red');
  }
}
```

Comment: `onEdit` only works on the value if it is changed manually on the spreadsheet. I need the cell text font to update when the cell value is updated indirectly because of data in other cells. Updated question to reflect.

Comment: `onEdit(e)` triggers when any value is changed. So there's no problem changing A3 specifically when A1 or A2 is changed. Code is different ofc.

Answer (score 1):

### `onEdit()` has [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and might not trigger if the cell values are changed externally, e.g. through script execution.

For this case, consider to install a `time-driven trigger` instead, which runs e.g. every minute, if desired.